# Unknown attribute error after using rename_column in migration in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I'm working on a Rails 3 app and I'm trying to update my user model. I had a "role" attribute that I changed to "is_admin" attribute with the following migration.

```
class ChangeRoleToIsAdminForUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def up
     rename_column :users, :role, :is_admin
   end

   def down
     rename_column :users, :is_admin, :role
   end
end
```

After that, I ran the following to make the changes of the schema.rb file.

```
rake db:migrate
```

Here is the resulting schema.rb file.

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20150102142012) do

  [...]

  create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at",      :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",      :null => false
    t.string   "login"
    t.string   "password_digest"
    t.string   "salt"
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "activated"
    t.string   "is_admin"
  end

end
```

You can see that the attribute was modified successfully. The problem is with my tests. I use Rspec. All of my tests worked just fine before the change of the attribute's name. Now, when I run my tests, I get the error

```
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute: is_admin
```

Here is part of my test file. The error is said to be at the line ***.

```
describe 'testing attributes' do

  before(:each) do
    @valid_attributes = {name: 'Un Tuteur',
                       login: 'tuteur',
                       password: 'password',
                       password_confirmation: 'password',
                       email: 'emilie.picard.cantin@gmail.com',
                       activated: 'oui',
                       is_admin: 'usager'}
    @user = User.new(@valid_attributes)  ***
    @user.save
  end

  [...]
end
```

I have changed the attribute name in my user.rb file and my users_controller.rb file. I don't know what the problem is...

Comment: Please post your model `User`

Comment: Do you define `attr_accessible` in your `User` model? And a bit different question - why do you pass `'oui'` string as your `activated` param - wouldn't it be better to make it boolean and hold `true` or `false`?

Comment: yes you can make `is_admin` as a `boolean` field instead a `string`

Comment: The reason is : I was a noob when I wrote this the first time :P. I'm still learning, but I want to update the model to fix this kind of things. I used strings everywhere and it's a mess, even though it works. Thanks for the suggestions !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please run `rake db:test:prepare` before running specs

Answer (score 0):

`RAILS_ENV=test rake db:migrate` should fix the problem, as running `rake db:migrate` applies changes only in development environment